# How do you put multiple textures on one model?

Tags: texturing

I have had problems with multiple textures on models for months, looked at plenty of tutorials, but I just don't get it, plus every help thread I can find is written as if you already understand what things are, and I don't know how the things work fully, so simple question, how do I get more then one texture to work on a model?
Upper picture shows how the model is supposed to look, with transparent glass windows, lower one is in Blender, I can't get it to work, whatever I do.
I need step by step explanation cause I'm slow.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Enter edit mode - select the faces you want a new material on - on the right (the box where it says _material.001_ in your image) - hit the plus button to the right of the box to add a new _material slot_ then press the plus button _below_ the box to add a new material to that slot. Press the _Assign_ button to apply the material to the selected faces. Do this for as many different materials as you need. Once you have a list populated with materials, you can just select faces on your mesh, select the material by name, and assign it to those faces.

Comment: Have you made this model or downloaded it? Is it properly UV unwrapped? The UV map does not look right, does it? When the blue areas on the left are the glass then the model (on the right) looks a bit random textured.

Comment: I forgot to add, because you are using EEVEE, transparency is black (opaque) by default - scroll down in the material settings for your glass material and change the blend mode from _opaque_ to something else if you want to be able to see through the "glass".